# How to Get The Taxonomy Term in Custom Post Type Loop Inside a Wp Query

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to get the **term** of each post while running WP Query. I tried this inside the loop

```
$term = $loop->get_queried_object();
echo  $term->name;
```

but I am still getting custom Post Type registered name instead of getting the Term!

```
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'orderby' => 'title', 
        'order' => 'ASC', 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

     $term = $loop->get_queried_object();
     echo  $term->name; 

     echo  get_the_title(); 

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Hi, it is Custom Taxonomy, but what I need is the `Term` not the Tax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `get_the_terms`. try the below code.

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'services',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 8, 
    'orderby' => 'title', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your-custom-taxonomy-name' );
    $terms = join(', ', wp_list_pluck( $terms , 'name') );

    echo $terms;

    echo  get_the_title(); 

endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: As always, great answer!